# How to check values of an attribute if it is present in json schema using karate framework

Tags: karate

I can have a response as:

```
 { id: '123', name: 'foo' }`
```

if the user has not a dog

OR

```
{ id: '123', name: 'foo', dog: {id: '123', color: 'brown'} }`
```

if the user has a dog.

In my feature I have:

```
* def schema = { id: '#string', name: '#string', dog: {id: '#string', color: '#string'} }`
* match response == schema
```

The prb is that if I have a user without dog in response, I have this error:

```
path: $[0].dog, actual: null, expected: {id=#string, label=#string}, reason: actual value is null
```

How can I check the attribute 'dog' in my schema?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in one step, also refer to the doc on [schema validation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation):

```
* def dogSchema = { id: '#string', color: '#string' }
* def schema = { id: '#string', name: '#string', dog: '##object' }

* def response1 = { id: '123', name: 'foo' }
* match response1 == schema
* match response1 contains { dog: '##(dogSchema)' }

* def response2 = { id: '123', name: 'foo', dog: { id: '123', color: 'brown' } }
* match response2 == schema
* match response1 contains { dog: '##(dogSchema)' }
```

Edit: well this is embarassing, I realized this trick is not well documented:

```
* def dogSchema = { id: '#string', color: '#string' }
* def schema = { id: '#string', name: '#string', dog: "#('##(dogSchema)')" }

* def response1 = { id: '123', name: 'foo' }
* match response1 == schema

* def response2 = { id: '123', name: 'foo', dog: { id: '123', color: 'brown' } }
* match response2 == schema
```

Edit2: this will be improved in the next version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/248

Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56987803/143475 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70006027/143475

Comment: thank you, it works. I've put the schema in a json file and put double ## here: `dog: "##('##(dogSchema)')"`. Two kind of responses can be validated. It's much easier than with Json Validation and much better.

Comment: @nirind this will be made easier in the next version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/248