# How to use templating in karate specific json schema

Tags: jsonschema, karate

I am trying below in Karate.

I have a json schema ( for response validation) in .json file. There are few REGEXs that are common in many schemas. I want to extract them into one common file as key value pairs and use it across other schemas. Is it possible? if so, how can I do that? Is templating allowed in json schema?

## Example:

## Sample Json Schema File ( sample-response.json):

```
{
  "response": {
    "name": "#string",
    "amount": "#regex ^(-?)([0]|[1-9][0-9]{0,15})[.][0-9]{2}$"
  }
}
```

## Feature File

```
Feature: Example feature

  Background:

  * def sampleResponse = read('./sample-response.json');



  Scenario: Example scenario

    When url 'https://someurl.com'
    And method get
    Then status 200
    And  match response == sampleResponse
```

## What would I like to Do?

I would like to store the amount regex in json file as a reusable variable and use templating in json file to replace it.
Is it possible?

```
{
  "response": {
    "name": "#string",
    "amount": "{{get regex from this template}}"
  }
}
```

Comment: edit your question to give one or two SIMPLE examples and try again. also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @PeterThomas, Updated more details

Comment: You can use the $ref keyword in JSON Schema to reference parts of other JSON Schema files. Sorry I can't provide further details right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [Embedded expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions) work even when [reading files](https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files).

So do this:

```
{
  "response": {
    "name": "#string",
    "amount": "#(amount)"
  }
}
```

And then do this:

```
Background:
* def amount = 100
* def sampleResponse = read('sample-response.json')
```

If you want the `amount` to come from another JSON file, why not, say this below is `data.json`:

```
{ "amount": 100 }
```

Then you do this:

```
Background:
* def data = read('data.json')
# you don't need the next line if you use "data.amount" as the embedded expression
* def amount = data.amount
* def sampleResponse = read('sample-response.json')
```

Comment: Is it possible to make data.json available as global for all features, instead reading it in each feature file?

Comment: @Farhan yes, set it in `karate-config.js`: `config.data = read('data.json');`

Comment: well. That of that initially. But a bit confused about what api calls are available in js and feature files.

Comment: Btw, Is there a way I can debug js files/ inline JS in feature files from IDE?

Comment: @Farhan you can't, and this is one reason we recommend you keep your JS to a minimum and use Java if you have some very complex custom logic. that said, the Karate UI solves for debugging to a large extent: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-UI