# Karate - Conditional JSON schema validation

Tags: karate

I am just wondering how can I do conditional schema validation. The API response is dynamic based on `customerType` key. If `customerType` is `person` then, person details will be included and if the `customerType` is `org` organization details will be included in the JSON response. So the response can be in either of the following forms

```
{
    "customerType" : "person",
    "person" : {
        "fistName" : "A",
        "lastName" : "B"
    },
    "id" : 1,
    "requestDate" : "2021-11-11"
}
```

---

```
{
    "customerType" : "org",
    "organization" : {
        "orgName" : "A",
        "orgAddress" : "B"
    },
    "id" : 2,
    "requestDate" : "2021-11-11"
}
```

The schema I created to validate above 2 scenario is as follows

```
{
    "customerType" : "#string",
    "organization" : "#? response.customerType=='org' ? karate.match(_,personSchema) : karate.match(_,null)",
    "person" : "#? response.customerType=='person' ? karate.match(_,orgSchema) : karate.match(_,null)",
    "id" : "#number",
    "requestDate" : "#string"
}
```

but the schema fails to match with the actual response. What changes should I make in the schema to make it work?

```
Note : I am planning to reuse the schema in multiple tests so I will be keeping the schema in separate files, independent of the feature file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you refer to this answer which I think is the better approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336682/143475

That said, I think you missed that the JS `karate.match()` API doesn't return a boolean, but a JSON that contains a `pass` boolean property.

So you have to do things like this:

```
* def someVar = karate.match(actual, expected).pass ? {} : {}
```

Comment: Now the problem half solved. The problem I now face is, if customerType is person, then getting error all key-values did not match, expected has un-matched keys: [organization]. Modified schema is {
    "customerType" : "#string",
    "organization" : "#? karate.match(response.customerType, 'org').pass ? karate.match(_, organizationSchema).pass : true)",
    "person" : "#? karate.match(response.customerType, 'person').pass ? karate.match(_, personSchema).pass : true",
    "id" : "#number",
    "requestDate" : "#string"
}