# Karate - Conditionally validating Json schema

Tags: karate

I am trying to write JSON schema for the below response. The response is dynamic it can be a `person` details or `organization` details. If the `customerType` in the response is `person`, then the response will contain person object (organization object will not be available). If the `customerType` is `org`, organization details will be included in the response (person object will not be available). Two different flavors of the expected response is given below

```
{
    "customerType" : "person",
    "person" : {
        "fistName" : "A",
        "lastName" : "B"
    },
    "id" : 1,
    "requestDate" : "2021-11-11"
}
```

---

```
{
    "customerType" : "org",
    "organization" : {
        "orgName" : "A",
        "orgAddress" : "B"
    },
    "id" : 2,
    "requestDate" : "2021-11-11"
}
```

I am trying to valid the above condition using the schema as given below

```
{
    "customerType" : "#string",
    "organization" : "#? karate.match(response.customerType, 'org').pass ? karate.match(_, organizationSchema).pass : true)",
    "person" : "#? karate.match(response.customerType, 'person').pass ? karate.match(_, personSchema).pass : true"),
    "id" : "#number",
    "requestDate" : "#string"
}
```

The problem I am currently facing is that, if `customerType` in the response is `person`, it throws below error

```
all key-values did not match, expected has un-matched keys: [organization]
```

Is there any way I can specify in the schema that if person object is available, organization object will not be available and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on doing this in one "single" schema, then Karate is not the tool for you. Otherwise, read on.

Karate encourages re-use of schema "chunks". Here are two possible solutions to your requirement. I hope you do more reading on how you can embed JS inside Karate script, and manipulate JSON before doing a match, there are even ways to "merge" JSON using `karate.merge()` if you really get fancy. You don't need to always do "exact" matches, sometimes `contains` gets the job done just fine.

```
* def personSchema = { firstName: '#string', lastName: '#string' }
* def orgSchema = { orgName: '#string', orgAddress: '#string' }
* def schema = { customerType: '#string', id: '#number' }

* def response1 = { customerType: 'person', person: { firstName: 'Foo', lastName: 'Bar' }, id: 1 }
* match response1 contains schema
* def extra = response1.person ? { person: '#(personSchema)' } : { organization: '#(orgSchema)' }
* match response1 contains extra

* def response2 = { customerType: 'org', organization: { orgName: 'Foo', orgAddress: 'Bar' }, id: 2 }
* if (response2.person) schema.person = personSchema; else schema.organization = orgSchema
* match response2 == schema
```

All that said, I **strongly** discourage "clever" tests like this, it just leads to maintainability issues. Please just stick to plain-vanilla scenarios as far as possible and set up your test / request so that you 100% know what the response is going to be. Please take some time and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475